# Directory Symbolic Links do not appear in Start Menu/All apps on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link, start-menu

In windows 7 I had a folder in "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs" that was a symlink to a UNC path on a network share. That folder (and the programs inside it) was then available from the Start Menu->All Programs menu.

When I upgraded to Windows 10, that folder doesn't appear in Start Menu->All Apps. It doesn't seem to matter whether the symlink is to a local folder or a network share, or whether it's a symlink or a junction.

Any thoughts about how to accomplish this on Windows 10?

Comment: A bit late to this question I'm afraid. But is the drive automatically connected to on restart?

Comment: @JulianKnight The way I had it set up on Windows 7 it didn't point to a mapped drive, just a UNC share. In other words I linked directly to \\mycomputer\myshare\myfolder as opposed to mapping \\mycomputer\myshare as Z: and then linking to Z:\myfolder. But that was a good idea, so I tried the mapped drive approach, and unfortunately that doesn't work either.